# Why is the `express` executable not working in my command prompt?

Tags: node.js, windows, express, web-development-server, express-generator

I installed Node.js, then created a new folder on my C:\ and [installed an Express skeleton](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) using:

```
npx express-generator
```

Now I just want to see the express options using `express -h`, but when I do so it gives this error:

> 'express' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

This is the beginning of the tutorial I followed: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html

Is there a missing step or something? Where did this go wrong?

Comment: Note, it's not a "keyword", it's a command or "executable" in the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

`express` is a command name, see the `bin` configuration in [package.json#L37](https://github.com/expressjs/generator/blob/v4.16.1/package.json#L37).

```json
"bin": {
  "express": "./bin/express-cli.js"
}
```

Also, have a look at the [`bin`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#bin) configuration of npm to know what's it.

You can install the `express-generator` globally, then use the `express` command to run the `./bin/express-cli.js` script.

```
$ npm install -g express-generator
$ express -h
```